# Particle start frame not exceeding 200 with python code

Tags: python, particles, keyframes, emission

When I am writing the code to start the emitter type particle at a particular frame, the start frame is not going beyond 200. Like if I give `frame_start = 300` its starting at 200. But if I give `frame_start = 190` its taking the value. But the frame end is taking whichever value I give. I attach the picture for reference. Please help. I am stuck[image]

Comment: Hi. https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/ should help with taking clearer screenshots. The current ones are quite hard to see. Also, if you need to include code, please include the code as text and not an image, so that people can test your code easily. Thanks.

Comment: May i ask which version of Blender you use? I used python to set the `bpy.data.particles["star1"].frame_start = 400` and it did work in version 2.83 stable. If you use an older version, i'd recommend to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the `bpy.data.particles["star1"].frame_start = 400` in Blender 2.83 and it worked fine.

In Blender 2.82 though it did indeed set the **Frame Start** value only to 200 as mentioned in the question.

[image]

The reason is Blender making internally sure, that the start value can't exceed the end value, which by default is 200. Should you set the end value to 400 and try to set the start value to 500, it will result in the start value being capped at 400 as well.

**There are 2 Solution possible:**

1. Update to Blender 2.83, which as i mentioned solves the issue, and sets the start and end value to the highest if the start value exceeds the old end value.
2. Stick with Blender 2.82 for whatever your reasons may be, but then you have to first set the `frame_end` value to be higher then the wanted `frame_start` value for this to work. Means in your code, just move the line where you set the `frame_end` above the line where you set the `frame_start`.

With solution 2, it would need to look like this:

```
bpy.data.particles["star1"].frame_end = 489
bpy.data.particles["star1"].frame_start = 319
```

Comment: I am currently using Blender 2.82. Thank you very much for the solution. It worked perfectly. I will try to update as soon as I can.